# Cannot access androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner

Tags: java, android, android-maps

I have the following class.

```
public abstract class AbstractMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

Unfortunately, but for unknown reasons this class is underlined in red and the following message appears: `Cannot access androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Updating "androidx.appcompat" version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 or above will help.

It's just Android Studio warning that you won't be able to use "savedstate" library.

The latest stable (non alpha) version is 1.2.0.

```
implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0
```